# Centering an element within an absolutely positioned element

Tags: css

I have something pretty simple I want to do. I'm still working through all the gotchas of CSS, so bear with me. I want to essentially take a div, put it `position: absolute; left: 10px; right: 10px; bottom: 10px`, then take its children and center them horizontally within the browser. [This is my attempt at doing so](http://jsfiddle.net/rfkrocktk/grwuN/):

HTML:

```
<div class="notificashun-holder">
    <div class="alert-message info notificashun">
        <p>Hello, World!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notificashun-holder {
    display: block;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

.notificashun {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The thing is, I'm using Bootstrap and the `alert-message` class makes items `display: block`, so I need to "shrink" them down to normal size (to fit only the size of their contents).

Can anyone help me do this? I simply need to make `notificashun-holder` be ten pixels from the left, right, and bottom of the browser, and `notificashun` be only as big as it needs to be and be centered within `notificashun-holder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using an `inline-block` element for the `.notificashun`, it can be affected by the `text-align` property, so to make it centered, just apply the `text-align: center;` property to your `.notificashun-holder`:

```
.notificashun-holder {
    display: block;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;

    /*New property:*/
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Nice, that solves it! Is there a better way of doing what I'd like to accomplish?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's about the best way I can see, if you specifically need that element to be an `inline-block`, since that conveniently keeps it minimum-sized. Nothing wrong with the way you've done it at all.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Yeah, I can't make it just inline, it messes up Bootstrap's CSS. Thanks!